# How to load data from offline text word list into string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

Working on an application that checks HTML documents to see if they contain specific words. Using `fs.readFileSync` to read the HTML, then using `fs.writeFile` to write it to a text document. Then checks the text document to see if it contains the defined words.

The way word list id defined in the code is:

```
var words = ./wordlist.txt
```

If defined the words separately in variables, it works fine, e.g.

```
var words = "stack", "cats", "dogs"
```

but if reading them from the text file which is formatted like

```
"stack", "cats", "dogs"
```

it stops working and return a string saying the words were not found.

The way I'm reading the word list file is this:

```
var posWord = "./wordlist.txt";
var positiveWords = fs.readFileSync(posWord, 'utf8', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("There was an error in reading the Positive Word list, refer to wordFunc()")
    }
});
```

`console.log(positiveWords)`, gives the whole word list with the correct formatting

Comment: `positiveWords` is a single string. If you want an array, you need to use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to separate the string into multiple strings. Then you'd need to remove the quotes, and the extra spaces. I suggest storing your words without quotes and with only a comma between them, like `stack,cats,dogs`.

Comment: Have a look at the [docs for `readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options). You probably expected the return value to be the parsed list of words (i.e. a string array) when it's really a string (or, buffer). You need to split `positiveWords` like so: `const words = positiveWords.split('\\s*,\\s*');`

Comment: @HereticMonkey , thanks for that clarification, even after storing the data properly, and using split functions, the program still doesn't find the word in the file, I will post the entire code on gitHub i'm at a dead-end right now as i'm completely new to Javascript. https://github.com/Taltarara/java/blob/master/test.js is the link to the whole code till now

Answer (score 0):

When you try to read them from the .txt file it will return as a string which represent the line , not as array as you expected
So you hav to convert it into array with split() function

```
var posWord = "./wordlist.txt";
var positiveWords = fs.readFileSync(posWord, 'utf8',   function (err) {
if (err) {console.log("There was an error in reading the Positive Word list, refer to wordFunc()")}})
Words=posWord.split(',');
```

Comment: This didn't work, if I try
    posWord.split(',') it just makes the array into [ ' ./wordlist.txt ' ]. I also tried use the same split method with var positiveWords, that makes it output as an array with the proper formatting but it still doesnt find the word in the file. Which is there and I have checked that multiple times